# Getting User Hashes from AD

Tags: mysql, bash, security, hash, active-directory

I'm setting up a MySQL Database and try to enable the users to login with their active directory username and password. I could extract their names from the AD, but now im stuck in getting their hashes. I googled around and all solutions I could find sound like I'm going to hack our AD. Is there a secure (and maybe easy?) way to get the hashes, so I can store them in my mysql.user table?

I'm operating from an Ubuntu 14.04 system and have an admin account in the AD, I can authenticate via Kerberos, most parts of my script are written in bash.

I asked my boss for permission, he's fine with this solution.

Thanks for your help

Edit: I'm also open-minded for any other solution, if my users can login to the database with their AD username and password, maybe with a third-party-authenticator like Kerberos?

Comment: There is a plugin for AD authentication: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-authentication-plugin.html

Comment: Or you could use LDAP in your scripts.

Comment: @Ashigore The plugin seems to be restricted to MySQL Enterprise Version, but i'm going to read about LDAP.

Comment: I didn't find a way to get the password/hash of a user from AD through LDAP - is the password stored as a attribute of the user? Is there a command to fetch it?